# Python pandas dataframe reduce operation along row

Tags: python, pandas, analysis

I have a pandas dataframe with one column and 100 rows. I would like to merge all the values of a column into one single value. 
Ex:

```
    S.No  Text 
    0      abc 
    1      def 
    2      ghi 
    3      jkl 
    4      mno
```

I want the result to be `"abcdefghijklmno"` as a one single value.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask a new one. Do not change your previous questions.

Answer (score 3):

Two pandas way

```
df.Text.sum()
Out[72]: 'abcdefghijklmno'


''.join(df.Text)
Out[77]: 'abcdefghijklmno'
```

Using for loop .

```
s=''
for x,y in df.iterrows():
    s+=y['Text']
```